# Invoke a Major Compaction in one node or in all nodes

Tags: cassandra

Good day guys. I'm still a noob to Cassandra so please bear with me.

My question is when I run a major compaction, do I have to run it in all the nodes or do I only have to run it in one node and that will trigger a major compaction in all of the remaining nodes?

Answer (score 3):

If using `nodetool compact` it will execute a major compaction only on the cassandra node you are running nodetool against.  I would refrain from doing major compactions on all nodes at once in production, as compaction has performance implications.  You should also have a good reason to do a major compaction, since it is an expensive operation and is not something you would do in most use cases.

Comment: Our use case is to use cassandra to store data that we use to validate the transactions that we process. Our application only needs that data for no more than 5 minutes. We delete that data immediately after the validation has been performed. Our use case produces a lot tombstones that's why we're thinking of scheduling regular major compactions

Comment: Have you considered using TTLs (http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html) and setting gc_grace_seconds to 0  instead of explicitly deleting your data?   This way you will have no tombstones and the expired data will go away much more quickly (yet will still stick around for a while).

Comment: Another thing to look into is the recently introduced Date-Tiered Compaction Strategy (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datetieredcompactionstrategy) which keeps mutations together based on when they were created.

Answer (score 2):

Your data model sounds very much like a queue, which is a well known cassandra antipattern.

Generally speaking, if you wanted your data to only live for 5 minutes at a time, forcing major compaction is probably the worst thing you can do - ideally you'd want to use TTLs, or perhaps drop your GCGS very low and consider using Date Tiered Compaction rather than Size tiered or Leveled, so that the entire sstables can be dropped quickly and efficiently.